# how to check variable type is GUID or not in jquery?

Tags: jquery, odata, guid

I have a database with type GUID and the value of column is `"33c3ccbc-b6bb-4caa-ab10-338aa95f366e".`

In jquery the type of GUID column is showing as string, but need to perform operation in odata. So how to check if the variable type is GUID or not in jquery.

Comment: You cannot get type as `GUID`. You'll need `regex` to check pattern.

Comment: can you share me code snippet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/j9t1ts06/ Check this

Answer (score 25):

There is no such thing as a GUID in Javascript.  You need to do some string manipulation to determine if the given string is a valid GUID. Using a regular expression seems ideal for this task.

This regular expression will match a GUID:

> /[a-f0-9]{8}(?:-[a-f0-9]{4}){3}-[a-f0-9]{12}/i

This method will test if the given string is a valid GUID (not tested, just written from the top of my head)

```
function isGuid(value) {    
    var regex = /[a-f0-9]{8}(?:-[a-f0-9]{4}){3}-[a-f0-9]{12}/i;
    var match = regex.exec(value);
    return match != null;
}
```